# Obtaining time complexities by simplifying the denominator?

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the big-O time complexities of the function

> f(x) = (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1)

and the function

> f(x) = (x<sup>3</sup> + 5 log x)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1)

This would be pretty straightforward if I could eliminate the +1 terms on the denominators of the fractions, since then I could just divide through by x<sup>4</sup>. How can I eliminate them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with big-O, it often helps to lower-bound and upper bound the value without necessarily getting the exact value.

For example, given (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1), one thing that might be helpful is to note that for x ≥ 1, that

> (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(2x<sup>4</sup>) ≤ (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1) ≤ (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/x<sup>4</sup>

Now that you've got everything sandwiched, you can just simplify everything from there quite simply to get

> (1/2)(x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup>) ≤ (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1) ≤ (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/x<sup>4</sup>
>
> > (1/2)(1 + 1 / x<sup>2</sup> + 1 / x<sup>4</sup>) ≤ (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1)/(x<sup>4</sup> + 1) ≤ 1 + 1 / x<sup>2</sup> + 1 / x<sup>4</sup>

The first half of the inequality gives you that your expression is Ω(1), and the second half gives you that it's O(1). Therefore, the expression is Θ(1).

Try using this same trick to simplify the second of these.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Invwr- It's the HTML &lt;sup&gt; tag. :-)

Comment: Thx and sry for plagiarizing your format style but I really like it :D

Answer (score 2):

The definition of big-O notation goes like this: we write f(x) = O(g(x)) when there exist M - real and x0>0 such that for every x > x0 is true that |f(x)| ≤ M |g(x)|.

For case 1 we will prove that f(x) = O(1). Let g(x) = 1. Picking M = 2 and x0 = 0 gives us that

> |(x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1) / (x<sup>4</sup> + 1)| = (x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1) / (x<sup>4</sup> + 1) ≤ (x^4 + (x^4 + 1) + 1) / (x<sup>4</sup> + 1) (since x<sup>2</sup> <= x<sup>4</sup> + 1 for x > 0) = 2 = M|g(x)|

So after all this we will get that f(x) = O(1). I hope this would also help for the second example. I think you got the idea. You have just to pick the appropriate M, x0 and g and prove the inequality.